# Remove imellipse after double click MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, roi

Just wondering how I can get rid of the imellipse after calling it in MATLAB. Currently I call it, double click it to plot the ellipse on my image, then I want to remove the ellipse tool.

I have a GUI, which I click a pushbutton to make an imellipse. After double clicking the imellipse, an outline is plotted onto my image and the dimensions saved to some matrix.

After double clicking it, resulting in a plot onto my image, I would like the ellipse ring (created from the function) to disappear. It just seems to stick around on the image (is this normal, or should it disappear?).

I can include my code, it just seems irrelevant to the problem (remove imellipse after double clicking).

I hope this is more clear!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add some more context? The question is not a good fit as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imellipse` creates a ROI on the figure, which can be removed if you delete the associated ROI object.

Let's suppose you have used `imellipse` like this -

```
Lesion = imellipse(handles.axes1);
```

Then, get all the information that you need from `Lesion` and then delete it. For example, if you need the mask information from it, store it somewhere.

```
LesionMask = Lesion.createMask();
```

Now, delete the ROI object which is `Lesion`.

```
delete(Lesion); %// Deletes the ROI related to imellipse
```

Read more about how to handle ROIs at [**`Region-of-interest (ROI) base class Documentation`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imroi.html)

Comment: Great thanks! Either you use the exact notation as I do, or you managed to see my code through some other means. Crazy world we live in! Cheers

Comment: @BobDole Or I have answered your previous question.

Comment: You are so boss! Thanks again, appreciate it.